# Getting data from 3 tables in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with structures like this:

```
store_locations
id        store_id        zip_code        city        state        last_updated
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         7438            37493           Seattle     WA           [timestamp]
1         7587            89574           Spokane     WA           [timestamp]


store_vehicles
id        store_id        vin_number
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         7438            [some vin number]
1         7587            [some vin number]


store_sold_vehicles
id        vin_number
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         [some vin number]
1         [some vin number]
```

I am trying to output a table with store details including `total_sales` for that location. Here is the query I'm attempting, but it is not working as I'm missing a GROUP BY statement but don't know how to add it.

```
   SELECT
      COUNT(sales.id) AS total_sales,
      locations.store_id AS store_id,
      locations.zip_code AS zip_code,
      locations.city AS city,
      locations.state AS state
    FROM store_locations locations
      INNER JOIN store_vehicles vehicles ON vehicles.store_id = locations.store_id
      INNER JOIN store_sold_vehicles sales ON sales.Vin = vehicles.Vin
    GROUP BY vehicles.Vin
```

Is this possible to achieve without multiple queries?

Edit: Expected output would be something like this:

```
[
  'store_id'=>8239,
  'zip_code'=>27103,
  'city'=>'San Francisco',
  'state'=>'CA',
  'last_updated'=>[timestamp],
  'total_sales'=>121
]
```

Comment: The expected output doesn't contains the sample data. so you need to tweak output as per the given raw data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by store and all non grouped elements:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(sales.id) AS total_sales,
  locations.store_id AS store_id,
  locations.zip_code AS zip_code,
  locations.city AS city,
  locations.state AS state
FROM store_locations locations
  INNER JOIN store_vehicles vehicles ON vehicles.store_id = locations.store_id
  INNER JOIN store_sold_vehicles sales ON sales.Vin = vehicles.Vin
GROUP BY locations.store_id, locations.zip_code, locations.city, locations.state
```

Comment: Causes this error `#1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'guitarma.locations.zip_code' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: A group by expression must contain all elements in your select, except for those that are used by an aggregation function.

Comment: Are you sure you are adding all fields? GROUP BY locations.store_id, locations.zip_code, locations.city, locations.state

Comment: I have updated my question with expected output. Is this output attainable?

Comment: That is the output that the query I posted as an answer should return. Please check that you are not missing something. The error you wrote tells me that you are not adding locations.zip_code in group by expression.

Comment: When I input this into my db, the query always times out. Is this just an incredibly inefficient way to do this or what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151731/discussion-between-gabriel-molina-and-danl).

Answer (score 1):

I think this what you want

```
SELECT store_locations.store_id , zip_code , city , state , last_updated , total_sales 
FROM store_locations JOIN (
  SELECT store_id , COUNT(c.id) AS total_sales
  FROM store_locations a JOIN store_vehicles b ON a.store_id = b.store_id JOIN store_sold_vehicles c ON b.vin_number = c.vin_number
  WHERE store_id = 8239
  GROUP BY store_id
) totalsales ON store_locations.store_id = totalsales.store_id
```

Comment: This gets the proper data on a dealer-by-dealer basis, but what about fetching them all at once?

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. In this query you are still specifying the `store_id` and in my ideal query, it fetches this data in an associative array for ALL locations aka all `store_id`s